# Xamarin: Where do find System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Tags: android, .net, matrix, xamarin

Does Xamarin provide Matrix class from .Net. I know there is a Android.Graphics Matrix but I want the .net version so I can use it across platform.

Comment: Most of System.Drawing is dependent on GDI, which is only available on Windows.

Comment: Will there be any c# convenient library just matrix coz I only need matrix in from that Drawing2D package.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. You can either write your own or find someone who has wrote their own and shared it. Here is a x-platform drawing library: https://github.com/praeclarum/NGraphics. I'm not sure if it handles matrix. You might need to just search for it yourself so that you can find the exactly what you're looking for.